# Generate a sprite according to box2d path

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I am making a path based game using cocos2d 2.0 which will randomly generate a path (curvature) for the player. This path has been created using box2d's b2EdgeShape. I want to place a sprite below that path, the route I have taken is this:

- The sprite to be shown below the path will repeat continuously whose height will always be greater than the height of the path (Parallax background)
- A white sprite will fit perfectly below the path using CCRenderTexture (**my real question**)
- A fragment shader will compare the alpha values of the white sprite with the sprite I have to show and multiply both the values. For each pixel where the sprite has to be shown the alpha value after multiplication will be 1 and hopefully I could achieve the effect I am looking for.

How do I make that white sprite to fit perfectly below the path created using CCRenderTexture. I tried to follow the Tiny Wings tutorial on RayWenderlich but that tutorial is based on OpenGL ES 1.1 and has some fixed pipeline functions that I can not port to OpenGL 2.0 (I have very little knowledge of OpenGL to begin with.) I would rather use cocos2d 2.0 which has OpenGL 2.0. I have worked on the  fragment shader, using a static white sprite and this approach can work if I can constantly get that white color underneath the path.
Can somebody please point me in the right direction? Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the white sprite is just an alpha mask, you don't need to do that.  Follow's Ray's example and I think all you have to change is:

In your -init:

```
// Built-in to Cocos2D v2.0
[self setShaderProgram: [[CCShaderCache sharedShaderCache] programForKey:kCCShader_PositionTexture]];

... Generate _hillVertices and _hillTexCoords as Ray does ...
```

In your -draw:

```
// Built-in to Cocos2D v2.0
[[self shaderProgram] use];
[[self shaderProgram] setUniformForModelViewProjectionMatrix];

// vertex data (glVertexPointer is depreciated)
glEnableVertexAttribArray ( kCCVertexAttrib_Position );
glVertexAttribPointer ( kCCVertexAttrib_Position, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, _hillVertices );

// texture data (glTexCoordPointer is depreciated)
glEnableVertexAttribArray ( kCCVertexAttrib_TexCoords );
glVertexAttribPointer ( kCCVertexAttrib_TexCoords, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, _hillTexCoords );

glDrawArrays ( GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, (GLsizei)_nHillVertices );
```

I have a working implementation that is similar (I used vertices and color coordinates, no texture) so I haven't actually compiled the code above.  Cocos2d v2.0 has built-in shaders for using vertices with textures, vertices with colors, vertices with textures and colors, etc.  Just pick the appropriate kCCShader_* key when you setShaderProgram and provide the right data.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, so you are saying that the alpha mask does not have to be a CCRenderTexture? If its not then how will I compare the alpha values in the other fragment shader for masking? If it is a CCRenderTexture then should I generate it using Ray's method i.e. instead of generating random colours, I should generate the white color 1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0?

Comment: Sorry, I did not get what you were trying to tell me previously, I have studied shaders now, a little bit, and now I am using kCCShader_Position_uColor instead of what you told me. I am getting a solid white color now under the path. This shader has a uniform variable u_color and the fragment shader is displaying that color. But I do not understand how am I getting this white color? I do not have that code in my project which was generating those CCRenderTextures anymore, I am just creating a plain path which has no color in it and shows the b2EdgeShape when I enable Debug Draw.

Comment: I'm saying you don't need an alpha mask to do this (and probably don't want to).  If you look in the section of Ray's tutorial called "Drawing the Hill", you'll see he's filling triangles with the ground texture (the tops of the triangles are the vertices from his curve).

Comment: If you still want to use the alpha mask, you'll have to create rectangles (or lines) whose height follow the curve and whose width is 1 pixel wide.  But using an alpha mask can be very costly because even when the alpha mask is 0.0, the pixel is still rendered.  Having an alpha mask of all 0.0 takes the same time to render as having all 1.0.  For large textures, this is significant overdraw.  Add multiple masked layers and your app will be really slow.  Ray's method only draws pixels below the curve and doesn't require programmatically making a large alpha mask.

Comment: Thank You, it works beautifully now. But there is still a small problem, the sprite I am using to display under the path has some shapes drawn to display grass and other things, these are all getting squished down because I am binding a 512x512 (1024x768) sprite in my draw. Is there some way to rectify this problem? This is why I was trying to use the masking technique, I faced this problem too when I used Ray's code in OpenGL 1.1, i.e. the sprite gets squished. It works fine if I have a plain sprite with a solid color though :)

Comment: _hillTexCoords[_nHillVertices++] = CGPointMake(pt0.x/512, 1.0f);

Comment: Sorry, the last comment got messed up.  That's easy to fix.  Notice where he sets the first two y-coordinates of _hillTexCoords to 1.0?  That means map the full height of the texture to the height of the triangle.  Set those to _hillVertices[_nHillVertices].y/<texture_height>.  If the hill is 512px hight and the texture is 512px high, the y coordinate will be 1.0.  If the hill shrinks to 256px, the y coordinate will be 0.5.  As an aside, you might want to increment the _nHillVertices index outside the array notation.  I had issues the way he wrote it.

Comment: Thank You Pat, you have made my day :) A thing I noticed while implementing your solution, _hillVertices[_nHillVertices].y was returning a value of 0 when I printed the value in the console. So I took pt0.y and pt1.y respectively and divided those values by 512. Now I have a really good fit underneath the path, but sometimes as I move along the path I have noticed the sprite is a bit skewed towards the right. This might have to do with some x values, but anyways thanks again for your help!